# xcode 8 doesn't support indexPathsForVisibleRows in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I have a project and use a lot of `indexPathsForVisibleRows`. Our project support iOS 8.0+ users. We migrate from Xcode7 to Xcode8 recently and find that Xcode 8 just support `indexPathsForVisibleRows` for only iOS9.0+ which doesn't work on iOS8. That is a disaster. Could anyone can help me?

Comment: in Objective-c or swift ?

Comment: Swift3: 
for myCell:AnyObject in tableView.visibleCells
        {
            let x = myCell as! CustomTableViewCell
            x.radioImageView.image = UIImage(named: "RadioEmpty.png")
        }

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C and Swift 2.3 & under, the [`indexPathsForVisibleRows` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614885-indexpathsforvisiblerows?language=objc) is still marked as working from iOS 2.0 (a.k.a. the beginning) & onwards.

If you're using Swift 3 (which comes with Xcode 8), then you'll be limited to iOS 9 & newer ([as the documentation states here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614885-indexpathsforvisiblerows)).

If this were my problem I would probably choose to write some kind of helper function / class method in Objective-C via a bridging header solely for this issue.